# Is it possible to extend react-docgen to also pick out custom properties on a component?

Tags: reactjs

Given a component with a custom object on it:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
     return <div>{ 'This is mine' }</div>
  }
}

MyComponent.propTypes = { ... }
MyComponent.customObject = {
  with: 'Some random info'
}

export const MyComponent
```

Is it possible to tell the `parse` fn in react-docgen to also pick out the `customObject` object and return it with the resulting component meta?

Answer (score 0):

[From the source code](https://github.com/reactjs/react-docgen/blob/e721493ccbca47cd36ccc60dc79c0530d6039c9c/src/main.js#L20-L32) it seems that you can send your own `handlers` array to the parse method, so you can write your own based off on one of the default handlers that does something similar to what you're trying to achieve.